# Problems with planner and ddl statements in Apache Calcite

Tags: java, ddl, create-table, apache-calcite, query-planner

When I try to validate a sql statement that contains "CREATE TABLE" it throws a error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Was not expecting value 'CREATE_TABLE' for enumeration 'org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlKind' in this context

    at org.apache.calcite.util.Util.unexpected(Util.java:1773)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.registerQuery(SqlValidatorImpl.java:2715)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.registerQuery(SqlValidatorImpl.java:2381)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateScopedExpression(SqlValidatorImpl.java:927)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validate(SqlValidatorImpl.java:633)
    at org.apache.calcite.prepare.PlannerImpl.validate(PlannerImpl.java:188)
```

I would like to know if is possible to validate a query using ddl statements in calcite?

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you provided the complete query and the code snippet that calls the planner API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stacktrace it seems that you are using the `Planner` interface. At the moment this interface does not support validation of statements that include DDL elements since it creates always an instance of [CalciteSqlValidator](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/prepare/CalciteSqlValidator.java).

In order to validate statements with DDL nodes you have to obtain an instance of [ContextSqlValidator](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/jdbc/ContextSqlValidator.java) but currently there is no high-level API to use this service.

Statements that are executed via a Calcite connection pass through the `ContextSqlValidator` so you can get ideas on how to instantiate this class by debugging a test case in [ServerTest](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/5f112a42a1aa62442a9e9306ac4700ed2152ac12/server/src/test/java/org/apache/calcite/test/ServerTest.java#L133).

Comment: Thanks, It helps me. I made a modification to not use CalciteValidator when executing DDL queries